# Spring MVC read file from local C: drive

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to have my web app read static resources (images) from the local C drive. To do this, I set up a dispatcher-servlet.xml to have the resources point to the local C drive folder, where the images are. The images' directory saves fine but the problem is reading the image directory from the database then have the web app show the image from the local.

```
    <mvc:resources location="file:///C:/upload_folder/" mapping="/UPLOAD_PATH/**" />
```

The folder is created on the C: drive but IntelliJ keep highliting the location value as 'file directory not found'

Also, after some testing, when I try to open the image in a new chrome tab, the URL root is not from the C drive but rather from the localhost

```
    http://localhost:8080/UPLOAD_PATH/img1Path/01/pic.jpg
```

where "img1Path/01/pic.jpg" (or "img1Path\01\pic.jpg" to be more accurate) is the directory saved in the database.

When I replace the localhost URL part with the local drive directory (i.e. file:///C:/upload_folder/img1Path/01/pic.jpg ), the image shows up.

I've tried every variation of slashes in the mvc resources part but nothing fruitful came out of it.

FYI, I'm only using Tomcat 8.5 as my server.

I'd appreciate any advice given. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your application runs from your server, and exists within that context. It's not "aware" of your C drive. It isn't supposed to be aware of it, neither.

Comment: So I'll have to point it to the root folder of the Tomcat Server then?